# Rails and Ajax communication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have on Java web app and another Rails web app.
I need to create a jquery ajax request from java  to Rails app.
How to do this.

I tried with this in jquery

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",           
            url:"someurl",              
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {
                //alert here
                }
```

How to give some response to this ajax request from rails?
Is the above code correct ?

In Rails,

```
def index
   @var1 = "myname"
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
   end
end
```

In index.js.erb,

```
 alert(@var1);
```

In the console ,

> Rendered index.js.erb (0.2ms) Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 6.2ms |
>   ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

Comment: Yes, it's correct and about as generic an example as you could possibly have given. What part of this isn't working for you?

Comment: def index
  render  :text => "OK"
end                                                                    Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms                                                                   but no data received in ajax

Comment: Can you share your index action code?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can do it in jquery post.

For example:-

```
$.post( yourURL, {data:data}, function(response){});
```

yourURL will be the url which should be a valid url to any of the controller method in rails app checked by rake routes.

Then you can create the action in the controller. Suppose you are posting to the 'your_method' of index controller.

action should respond as js . 
for example:-

in index controller define

```
def your_method

   #your code here

   respond_to do |format|
     format.js{}
   end
end
```

Make one js.erb file of the action. After posting to the method from ajax correctly, it will provide some response. Capture it in your response value in jquery post. and make required changes.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks...But no response received in Ajax...code in ajax is            $.ajax({
   type: "POST",   
   url:"someurl",   
   cache:false,
   success: function(data) {
    alert('success');
    
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("error");
   }                                                                      In Rails,  def index
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
   end
end                                                                    and In index.js.erb return 'hello'

Comment: If the ajax is posting to the same action without any error break in console, assign some value in index action like

def index
@text = 'hello'
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
end

then
alert (response) in $.ajax

Comment: value is evaluated correctly in index action def index
   var1 = 1
    var2  =2
    logger.debug " #{var1 + var2}"
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
   end
end

Comment: ok make the var1 and var2 to '@var1' and '@var2' as it may not access in js.erb file, then can you just do an alert in index.js.erb like alert(@var1).Hope this will work.

Comment: I added @var1, but no alert is coming. I am using Rails 3.0 and Ruby 1.8.7.... any jquery plugin or ajax plugin i have to install ? Since the jquery call is from java web app , I did not add any jquery/ajax dependencies in rails

Comment: check the application in firebug, if you are getting the error as jquery is not included put the gem for jquery as gem 'jquery-rails' then run bundle install.

make sure in your application.js there sholud these three lines
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs

Comment: No error in firefox. 200 OK.But no alert response from rails. No jquery code in my app , only in java web app , I have jquery code . Do I still need to add jquery dependencies in rails ?

Comment: Sorry, first alert('hello') then try with alert(<%= @var1 %>); in index.js.erb . as '@var1' is a ruby variable it cant directly type as javascript var.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was, Ajax does not work on cross domain.
Java is hosted in one domain and Rails in another domain... that was the issue in my case.

I handle Ajax in java side itself now. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you should add datatype option to your JQuery ajax.
And It's depends on what is the your rails response

```
dataType: 'script', dataType: 'json' or dataType: 'text' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for example your model name is Post and you are calling the post method in rails it will be something like that.

```
        $('#Button').on('change', function(event) {
          var selected_resource_id = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({ 
           type: 'POST', 
           url: "<%= post_path %>",
           data: { id: selected_resource_id }, 
           success: function (data) {  
            alert("Ajax success");
           }
          });
        });
```